# Prove or disprove $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ where $S_i\cap S_j = \varnothing \text{ or } S_i\text{ or } S_j$, has disjoint subcollection with same union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove $\{S_i\}_{i \in I}$ where $I$ is an index set, and just suppose $S_i \subset U$ for some set $U$ (this set should be irrelavant), and for all $i, j \in I$, $S_i\cap S_j = \varnothing  \text{ or } S_i\text{ or } S_j$,  has disjoint subcollection $T_i$ such that $\cup S_i =\cup T_i$.

The condition for all $i, j \in I$, $S_i\cap S_j = \varnothing  \text{ or } S_i\text{ or } S_j$, means that if any $ S_i \cap S_j \ne \varnothing$ , then $S_i \subset S_j$ or $S_j \subset S_i$.

It seems obvious to me. But I cannot find a rigorous way to state it. My best is to say something like "remove any set in ${S_i}$ if it's a subset of any other set."

Is it true? Or is it related to the cardinality of the index set $I$? Will it be easier to prove or disprove for the case that $I$ is countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\{1\}, \{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\cdots$. This sequence satisfies the hypothesis but the conclusion fails.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. For a concrete case that $S_i = [\frac{k_i}{2^{N_i}}, \frac{k_i+1}{2^{N_i}})$, where $k_i$ is some integer and $N_i$ is some positive integer, How should I do a statement for "removing the subset $S_i$ that is subset of some others"?

Comment: That’s really a different question, @onriv

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks. Tried 30 minutes and still cannot state it in details. I asked a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266450/