# Prove $\{C_i\}_{i=1,2,\cdots}$ has disjoint subcollection $\{D_i\}$ with $\cup C_i = \cup D_i$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory

For convenience, some definitions:

> A *dyadic cube* $C_{\mathbf{k},N}$ is given by
> $$
> C_{\mathbf{k}, N} \stackrel{\text { def }}{=}\left\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \frac{k_{i}}{2^{N}} \leq x_{i}<\frac{k_{i}+1}{2^{N}} \text { for } 1 \leq i \leq n\right\},
> $$
> where $\mathbf{k} \stackrel{\text { def }}{=}\left(\begin{array}{c}
> k_{1} \\
> \vdots \\
> k_{n}
> \end{array}\right)$ and $k_1, \dots, k_n$ are integers.
> And the $N$th *dyadic paving* of $\Bbb{R}^n$, denoted as $\mathcal{D}_N(\Bbb{R}^n)$, is the collection of cubes $C_{\mathbf{k}, N}$ at a single level $N$.

Show that any collection $\{C_i \}$, of all dyadic cubes $\cup \mathcal{D}_N(\Bbb{R}^n)$, has a subcollection $\{D_i\}$  such that
$$
\cup C_i = \cup D_i \text{ and } D_i \cap D_j = \varnothing \text{ for any i $\ne$ j} 
$$

All definitions are taken from Hubbard's book *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential forms*. I'm reading it on my own for a solid understanding on Multivariable Calculus and some intuitive yet still rigorous understanding on Manifold maybe.

Comment: Hint: start bu picking the cubes with $N=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks a lot! I wrote an answer for proving it in details with your hint. Could you check it please if have some time?

Answer (score 0):

I got some cumbersome way to state it:

Define $\{C_{i_{j,k}}\}$ as follow:

Define $\{C_{i_{1,k}}\}= \{C_{i_{1,1}}, C_{i_{1,2}}, \cdots, C_{i_{1,k}}, \cdots\} = \{C_i\} \cap \mathcal{D}_1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ be the subcollection of $\{C_i\}$ that is also a subcollection of $\mathcal{D}_1(\Bbb{R}^n)$.
For $j > 1$, define $\{C_{i_{j,k}}\}= \{C_{i_{j,1}}, C_{i_{j,2}}, \cdots, C_{i_{j,k}}, \cdots\}$ such that $C_{i_{j,k}} \in \mathcal{D}_j(\Bbb{R}^n)$ and $C_{i_{j,k}} \cap C_{i_{l,m}} = \varnothing$ for any $l < j$ and $m = 1,2,\cdots$.

Then $\cup C_{i_{j,k}} = \cup C_i$ and for any $C_{i_{j_1,k_1}}, C_{i_{j_2,k_2}}$, $C_{i_{j_1,k_1}} \cap C_{i_{j_2,k_2}} = \varnothing$. Prove as follows:

1. Since each $C_{i_{j,k}}$ is some $C_i$, $\cup C_{i_{j,k}} \subset \cup C_i$. If $x \in \cup C_{i}$, then $x \in C_{i_x}$ for some $i_x$. Suppose $C_{i_x} \in \mathcal{D}_{j_x}(\Bbb{R}^n)$. If there is some $C_{i_{j,k}}$ with $j < 
    j_x$ such that $C_{i_{j,k}} \cap C_{i_x} \ne \varnothing$. Then by definition of $\mathcal{D}_N(\Bbb{R}^n)$, $C_{i_x} \subset C_{i_{j,k}}$. Hence $x \in \cup C_{i_{j,k}}$; Otherwise by definition of $\{C_{i_{j,k}}\}$, $C_{i_x}$ is some $C_{i_{j,k}}$. Hence $x \in \cup C_{i_{j,k}}$ too.
2. If $j_1 = j_2$, by definition of $\mathcal{D}_N(\Bbb{R}^n)$, $C_{i_{j_1,k_1}} \cap C_{i_{j_2,k_2}} = \varnothing$. Otherwise suppose $j_1 < j_2$ without loss of generality. Then by definition of $\{C_{i_{j,k}}\}$,$C_{i_{j_1,k_1}} \cap C_{i_{j_2,k_2}} = \varnothing$ too.

Finally just denote $\{C_{i_{j,k}}\}$ as $\{D_i\}$.